# Emacs. Abbreving "." to ending sentence

Tags: emacs, symbols, abbreviation

I am an emacs newbie. I am trying to expand the character "." to ".  " (period with two spaces in order to be more effective in ending a sentence in emacs) with abbrevs. In other words, when I type a "." followed by a space, emacs put a ".  ".

I have put the next code in my abbrevs file, but it doesn't work.

```
(text-mode-abbrev-table)                                    
"."            0    ".    "
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Abbreviations trigger on space key, so what you tried to do is a little counter-productive, as you'd still have to type a space, but you can modify the character table / define special command for the mode / define input method, where what would be possible. Also, I think I'd get annoyed very soon about this abbrev when trying to types something like a file name / URL address etc. Not sure it's worth the trouble.

Comment: I've provided an answer below, but I urge you to reconsider your original purpose. I find it mildly infuriating when people double-space sentences. (unless, of course, you're writing in a language I don't read :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want this, but here it is:

Put this in `~/.emacs`:

```
(defun electric-dot ()
  (interactive)
  (if (and (looking-back "\\w") (not (looking-back "[0-9]")))
      (progn
        (self-insert-command 1)
        (insert "  "))
    (self-insert-command 1)))

(defvar electric-dot-on-p nil)

(defun toggle-electric-dot ()
  (interactive)
  (global-set-key
   "."
   (if (setq electric-dot-on-p
             (not electric-dot-on-p))
       'electric-dot
     'self-insert-command)))
```

Afterwards, use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`toggle-electric-dot`
to make each <kbd>.</kbd> insert `.`  , if it's after a word.
You can call it again to restore the default behavior.

As a side-note, there's a ton of *much* better ways
to improve your text input speed e.g. `auto-complete-mode`.
You can install it with `package-install`.

### UPD `electric-dot` inserts just a dot after digits.

### UPD Here's `electric-space` instead:

This one will insert an extra space if it's looking back
at a word followed by a dot.

```
(defun electric-space ()
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back "\\w\\.")
      (insert " "))
  (self-insert-command 1))

(defvar electric-space-on-p nil)

(defun toggle-electric-space ()
  (interactive)
  (global-set-key
   " "
   (if (setq electric-space-on-p
             (not electric-space-on-p))
       'electric-space
     'self-insert-command)))
```

Comment: @Juan His code *is* a keybinding. It's just more sophisticated and robust.

Comment: With all due respect, your code looks spectacular but that function can be achieved by a keybinding. 

`
(defun dot-spaces()                                                   
    (interactive)                                                     
    (insert ". "))                   
(global-set-key (kbd ".") 'dot-spaces)
`
It is ok for ending a sentence. But, what about decimals? If I put in my text a number like `3.1416` that function causes this `3. 1416`. That is why I need to map this string `. ` to `.  `.

Comment: Thank you very much! `electric-space` is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Install the key-chords package. Then define one like this.

```
(key-chord-define-global ". " ".  ")
```

Key chords accept a larger variety of keys then abbrev, so ". " might work. But the two keys have to be pressed in quick succession (which shouldn't be a problem here).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your abbrev does not work is because by default, abbrev names can only be composed of word-element characters (basically, alphanumeric chars), and `.` is not such a character.  You can circumvent this problem by changing the `:regexp` property of your `text-mode-abbrev-table` but it's really not worth the trouble.  Instead you can do

```
(defun my-electric-space-post-insert ()
  (and (eq (char-before) ?\s)
       (eq (char-before (1- (point))) ?.)
       (insert " ")))
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'my-electric-space-post-insert)
```